# How to implement multi-window support in my custom browser provider plugin

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I've updated to testcafe v1.9.4 and I would like to make use of the new multi-windows support.
However I use a custom browser provider.

When I run a test with openWindow I get the error

> Multi window mode is supported in Chrome, Chromium, Edge 84+ and
> Firefox only. Run tests in these browsers to use the "openWindow"
> method.

If I add the following methods to my browser provider

```
supportMultipleWindows: true,

  getActiveWindowId(browserId) {
    return this.openedBrowsers[browserId].activeWindowId;
  },

  setActiveWindowId(browserId, val) {
    this.openedBrowsers[browserId].activeWindowId = val;
  },
```

Then my browser will start, but no longer open the url of the page under test, it just hangs on the browser idle page.

I have not found any documentation and the  Testcafe browser provider generator seems to have not been changed to document or implement multi-window support.
Therefore I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, this feature is at the 'beta' stage. Implementation details may be changed before the release. This is why we don't announce 'multiple windows' support for a custom browser provider and cannot give any recommendations on the implementation of this feature. Once it is released, we will consider supporting multiple windows for custom browser providers.

---

**UPDATE**: Support for multiple browser windows was [released as a stable feature](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/blog/testcafe-v1-11-0-released.html#multiple-browser-windows-is-live-912) in TestCafe v1.11.0. Due to its complexity and a huge amount of browser-specific code, we decided to not implement support for additional browsers and custom browser providers. While there is a possibility that we will implement it some day, we do not have plans to address this in the nearest future

Comment: Is there any solution available now for this issue?

Comment: The multiple-window functionality is still in the beta stage. Moreover, we don't plan to introduce the `custom browser providers support` functionality in the release version. Could you please clarify for what browser provider you need this feature?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-provider-selenium I am using this library to run a test on the selenium grid and getting the above multi-window error.

Comment: This is a custom browser provider, and the TestCafe team does not maintain it. So, the author of that provider should support the 'multiple windows' functionality. However, at this moment, TestCafe does not support custom browser providers, as I mentioned before.

Comment: I show the latest version changelog of testcafe(release 2-3 days ago). it seems like still in beta mode. Thank you for your help @Alex